# Post data ajax to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to post the value when some click on delete. Please check the error

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         var checkid =  $('#delete').click(function(){ $(this).val();});,
         url: "survey-command.php",
         data: { checkid: checkid, }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       });
```

I dont know how pass the value to this checkid variable

Comment: So whats the problem? why do you think it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code I believe should look like this:

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
   var checkid= $(this).val(); //assuming $('#delete') is an input.
                               // otherwise use $('#delete').html();
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "survey-command.php",
         data: { checkid: checkid, }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$('#delete').click(function(){ 
var checkid = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",         
         url: "survey-command.php",
         data: { checkid: checkid, }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       });
});
```

Remove the Click from the $.ajax function as you need to fire the post event on the button click

Answer (score 0):

This the correct code that you need to use :

```
     $('#delete').click(function(){     
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "survey-command.php",
         data: { checkid: $(this).val();, }
            }).success(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
   });
```

Comment: ha ha ha ha Levuva Patel

Comment: Gr8, can we move this conversation to whats app ? ;-)